# External javascript not being run from React (CRA)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I have a plain HTML template which I am trying to convert into a small React app (using create-react-app). I have inserted the following script tags into the index.html file located in the public directory, but it doesnt seem to be running some of the scripts

```
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/TweenMax.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/owl.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/mixitup.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/appear.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/wow.js"></script>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/custom-script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

if i load the page and go into the console and type `$ === jQuery` it returns true, which tells me that the jquery.js file is being loaded, but a lot of functionality from the other files does not seem to work.

There are no errors being generated in the console either

Am i doing something wrong in the way i am bringing these files into the project?

Comment: Are you sure those resources are loaded by the browser? Check the network tab for these requests and http 404 errors

Comment: @keul it says status code 200 for all the scripts, so it looks like they are being loaded